# Inconsistencies with MysQL DATEDIFF Function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok, so I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `dates` WHERE firstDate IS NOT NULL AND secondDate IS NOT NULL  
AND DATEDIFF(secondDate, firstDate) >= 30
```

That query returns the value of 9. I then use the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `dates` WHERE firstDate IS NOT NULL AND secondDate IS NOT NULL  
AND DATEDIFF(secondDate, firstDate) >= 90
```

The second query returns a result of 12. How is that possible? Both dates are date data types in the MySQL Database.

Comment: Let me ask you this: why is it not possible?

Comment: This does not seem possible.

Comment: add [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to prove it

Comment: `SELECT firstDate, secondDate, DATEDIFF(firstDate, secondDate)` and you might find out what's wrong. What you've got here is a murder mystery with no evidence.

Comment: Since you increased the `datediff` in the `where` clause, it's possible you have more rows returned in the second query.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this

```
SELECT firstDate, secondDate, DATEDIFF(secondDate, firstDate) AS diff 
FROM `dates` WHERE firstDate IS NOT NULL AND secondDate IS NOT NULL
AND DATEDIFF(secondDate, firstDate) >= 30

SELECT firstDate, secondDate, DATEDIFF(secondDate, firstDate) AS diff
FROM `dates` WHERE firstDate IS NOT NULL AND secondDate IS NOT NULL
AND DATEDIFF(secondDate, firstDate) >= 90
```

Instead of the count of the resulting rows you will see the actual list of rows.
That might help you to figure this one out.